# Make url-rewrite in .htaccess file to work both ways

Tags: .htaccess, url-rewriting

I have the following .htaccess file:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^project/([0-9]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9]+)/(.+)?$ project.php?id=$1&pName=$2&urlPram=$3  [L,NC]

</IfModule>
```

when my url format is something like:

```
mysite.com/project/1/test/vw
```

everything works fine. But I would also like when the url is typed in the other format, to be rewritten to the first format.
i.e. When I type the url like this:

```
mysite.com/project.php?id=1&pName=test&urlParam=vw
```

I wants it to be turned into:

```
mysite.com/project/1/test/vw
```

Do I have to write another rule? or is it accomplished in some other way?

Comment: So you want a redirect when someone types in the url `mysite.com/project.php?id=1&pName=test&urlParam=vw`?

Comment: @putvande I don't know if it is a redirect that I need. I mean the same physical php file is going to serve both URLs, I just don't  want the url to appear in the address in this format <mysite.com/project.php?id=1&pName=test&urlParam=vw>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The current rewrite rule would not handle both the cases. Add the below rewrite rule as well.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /mysite/

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^project/([0-9]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9]+)/(.+)?$ project.php?id=$1&pName=$2&urlParam=$3&no-redir  [L,NC,QSA]

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !no-redir
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (^|&)id=([^&]+)&pName=([^&]+)&urlParam=([^&]+)
RewriteRule ^project\.php$ project/%2/%3/%4?  [R=301,L,NC]
```

Comment: This caused the URL to be:

mysite.com/project/1/test/vw?id=1&pName=test&urlParam=vw

Comment: Use `project/%2/%3/%4?` Notice the `?` at the end.

Answer (score 0):

You need one more external redirect rule. Use this code:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /project\.php\?id=([^&]+)&pName=([^&]+)&urlPram=([^&\s]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ project/%1/%2/%3? [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^project/([0-9]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9]+)/(.+)?$ project.php?id=$1&pName=$2&urlPram=$3 [L,NC,QSA]

</IfModule>
```

Comment: Same problem, In the localhost I type:
    `localhost/mysite/project.php?id=1&pName=test&urlParam=vw`
and it's turned into:
    `localhost/C:/xampp/htdocs/mysite/project/1/test/vw?id=1&pName=test&urlParam=vw`

Comment: Pls note that `mysite.com/project.php?id=1&pName=test&urlParam=vw` is different structure than `http://localhost/mysite/project.php?id=1&pName=test&urlParam=vw` Difference is `mysite` folder before `/project.php` segment.

Comment: I think I should have mentioned the subfolder, sorry. Thank you for your time. The above answer did what I wanted.